# Oracle APEX - chart displays decimal point

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a bar chart on my page where x-axis shows counts. The numbers are displayed with a decimal point (ex.: 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 etc.). I want to display integers instead: 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Without .5 and without decimal points. I se the x-axis Value section Format to `Decimal` and Decimal places to `0` but still not getting a desired result. Which settings do i need to tweak to have integers displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also setting the Step attribute to 1 did it for me.

[image]